# Return matching strings from two lists based on last 4 characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
list1 = ['1_Maths','2_Chemistry','10.1_Geography','12_History']
list2 = ['1_Maths', '2_Physics', '3_Chemistry','11.1_Geography','13_History']
```

I want to produce two outputs from list1 and list2 based on last 4 characters.

```
lists = [item for itm in list1 if itm in list2]
```

The above only prints `1_Maths`. Cannot think of a way to produce all the matching subjects.

```
last_4char = [sub[ : -4] for sub in list1]
```

This could be an idea but I'm not sure how I can implement this to product the exact results from list1/2

Output

```
print(new_list1)  = ['1_Maths','2_Chemistry','10.1_Geography','12_History']
print(new_list2)  = ['1_Maths', '3_Chemistry','11.1_Geography','13_History']
```

Comment: `[itm for itm in list1 if itm[-4:] in [item2[-4:] for item2 in list2]]`. Pay attention that this solution assume all the elements in lists has at least 4 chars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def common_4_last(list1, list2):
    return [[i for i in list1 if i[-4:] in {k[-4:] for k in list2}], [i for i in list2 if i[-4:] in {k[-4:] for k in list1}]
```

This will result to a list with 2 elements, one list for items form list1 and a second list for items from list2 that fit the criteria of common last 4

You can run the function for any pair of lists

For example for your given list1 and list2 result will be:

```
common_4_last(list1, list2)

[['1_Maths', '2_Chemistry', '10.1_Geography', '12_History'], ['1_Maths', '3_Chemistry', '11.1_Geography', '13_History']]
```

If you want the first list you can get it by

`common_4_last(list1, list2)[0]` and the same for second list

Comment: Any better way to do this if have three lists. The lists all have same names but the numbers are different.